# trim tailing - and add it leading for Numbers in shell

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a CSV file with numbers in double quotes and without double quotes and for some numbers. I have to fix the negative symbols for only numbers:  the tailing negative symbol has to be removed and added to the beginning.

Sample Input:

```
column 1, column 2, column 3, column 4, column 5
12-,"455,365.44-","string with quotes-and with a comma in between","4,432",6787
```

Sample Output:

```
column 1, column 2, column 3, column 4, column 5
-12,"-455,365.44","string with quotes-and with a comma in between","4,432",6787
```

Comment: When you say _string with quotes_, is that double quotes? How are they encoded? By doubling the `"` like in most CSV formats? Or with `\"` as sometimes seen? Can the strings contain newline characters? It would be better to have a real example there.

Answer (score 1):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,"]+|"[^"]+"' '
       NR==1; NR>1{ 
           for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { 
               if ($i~/^"?[0-9]+([0-9,.]+[0-9]+)?-"?$/) { 
                   sub(/-/, "", $i); 
                   sub(/[0-9]/, "-&", $i); 
               } 
               printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF? ORS:",") 
           } 
       }' file.csv
```

- `-v FPAT='[^,"]+|"[^"]+"'` - regex pattern defining field value
- `$i~/^"?[0-9]+([0-9,.]+[0-9]+)?-"?$/` - check if a field contains a number with trailing minus sign `-` (number could be double-quoted)

---

The output:

```
column 1, column 2, column 3, column 4, column 5
-12,"-455,365.44","string with quotes-and with a comma in between","4,432",6787
```

Comment: I see it's not working for the same data set I used. Still the negative remains  at tailing.

Comment: @Kiran, that's not true ... and here's the screenshot https://ibb.co/jbzZ9b

Comment: @Kiran  FPAT requires gawk version 4. What is the output of `gawk --version`?

Answer (score 0):

CSV data requires a CSV parser. Ruby has one:

```
$ cat file.csv
12-,"455,365.44-","string with quotes-and with a comma in between","4,432",6787

$ ruby -rcsv -e '
    CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) do |row|
        corrected = row.collect {|e| e.sub(/^([\d,.]+)-$/, "-\\1")}
        puts CSV.generate_line(corrected)
    end
' file.csv
```

```
-12,"-455,365.44",string with quotes-and with a comma in between,"4,432",6787
```

The CSV generator decided that the "string with quotes" did not need to be quoted because it does not contain a comma.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because of the quote stripping.

Answer (score 0):

awk solution that does not use `gawk` FPAT:

```
NR==1;

NR > 1 {
    $0 = $0","

    while ($0) {
        match($0, / *"[^"]*" *,|[^,]*,/)
        f = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)             # save what matched in f
        if (( f ~ /^"[0-9]([0-9,.]+[0-9]+)-"$/ ) ||
            ( f ~ /^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+-$/ ) ||
            ( f ~ /^[0-9]+-$/ )) {
            sub(/-/, "", f);
            sub(/[0-9]/, "-&", f);
        }
        $0 = substr($0, RLENGTH+1)                 
        printf "%s%s", f, (0 == NF ? "\n" : ",")
    }
}
```

Output for supplied sample file is:

```
column 1, column 2, column 3, column 4, column 5
-12,"-455,365.44","string with quotes-and with a comma in between","4,432",6787
```

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`, but not suitable for all sorts of `csv` formats, works for given sample

```
$ perl -ne '@cols=/"[^"]+"|[^,]+/g;
            map {s/"(.*)-"$/"-$1"/ or s/(.*)-$/-$1/} @cols;
            print join ",", @cols' ip.csv
column 1, column 2, column 3, column 4, column 5
-12,"-455,365.44","string with quotes-and with a comma in between","4,432",6787
```

- `@cols=/"[^"]+"|[^,]+/g` save fields in array
- `map {s/"(.*)-"$/"-$1"/ or s/(.*)-$/-$1/} @cols` change each element of array. The second substitution is used only if first doesn't succeed

  - change `(.*)` to `([\d,.]+)` to sort of restrict the matching to digits and `,` and `.` only. This would still match strings like `..,..-`
- `print join ",", @cols` print the changed array with `,` as separator

a bit of fun without using temp array

```
perl -ne 'print join ",", map {/^"/ ? s/"(.*)-"$/"-$1"/r : s/(.*)-$/-$1/r} /"[^"]+"|[^,]+/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` implementations supporting `-E`, assuming the double quotes embedded in string fields are encoded as `""` and that those string fields don't contain newline characters:

```
sed -E '
  :1
  s/^(("[^"]*"|[^"])*,)?([0-9.]+)-(,|$)/\1-\3\4/;
  s/^(("[^"]*"|[^"])*,)?"([0-9,.]+)-"(,|$)/\1"-\3"\4/
  t1' < file
```

Depending on the nature of the input, you may want to be stricter  in matching the numbers. For instance `([0-9.]+)-` here would match on `12-` but also on `...-`. If that type of input may occur in the input, you could change it to `([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)-` for instance.